# Fstream Initialization in a Class - Checking if File Opened

Tags: c++, class, exception, initialization, fstream

Example:

//Header File

```
class Example
{
    private:
            fstream InputObject;  

    public:
            Example();  

}
```

//Implementation File

```
Example::Example():InputObject("file_name.txt", ios::in) {}
```

From what I've read so far from similar questions, the only way, in the "older" version of C++, for initializing an fstream object in a class is to do so via member list initialization shown above.

Question:
If that really is the "only" way of initializing an fstream object in a class, what do we do if the file should fail to open?

Normally I'd run the fstream object through a check to make sure it opened properly, but this doesn't seem possible in this case.  Also, even if I could, how could I reinitialize the object if it failed to do so the first time through?

Comment: Just run the check in the body and use `.open()` if you want to try again.

Comment: `fstream` objects have an `open()` member function...

Comment: The only thing that was added in C++11 (apart from all the other things) is that you can now use `std::string` arguments directly for `fstream`...

Comment: @KerrekSB, I interpreted it as in-class member initialization, though it doesn't fix the checking or anything.

Comment: So I can't "initialize" the function with .open, but I can try to "reopen" it using .open in the body of the constructor?

Comment: @Artezul, Yes, `open()` basically does the same thing as the constructor.

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason I was convinced you couldn't initialize an fstream object the old fashioned way (InputObject.open(fileName)) inside a class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // This makes it so it doesn't look through libs that are not included when running

#include <fstream> //To Read write to files, to be able to
#include <iostream> // The basic stuff, cout, cin, etc.
using namespace std; // the capability of typing cout instead of std::cout
int main() // our main loop
{
fstream InputObject; // declaring InputObject as something that can write to a file
if(!Inputobject.open("File Name Here") // if it cant open the file
{
cout << "File not Open" << endl; // then write to console, " File not Open"
}

return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

You want to find out if the file is open, so using ! before the functio for opening file means , not open, so an if statement with !InputObject.open, will check if it is not open, if that is true, do something, so cout << "File is not open" will tell u if it is open or not.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I've read so far from similar questions, the only way, in the "older" version of C++, for initializing an fstream object in a class is to do so via member list initialization shown above.

That's not strictly true.
It is probably the preferred way of doing it. But you don't need to do it that way. And a failure simply sets the state to failed that can then be tested in the body of the constructor.

> If that really is the "only" way of initializing an fstream object in a class

No.

> what do we do if the file should fail to open?

Test and re-try in the body of the constructor.

> Normally I'd run the fstream object through a check to make sure it opened properly, but this doesn't seem possible in this case. Also, even if I could, how could I reinitialize the object if it failed to do so the first time through?

There are standard API to reset the state of a stream after a failure.

```
Example::Example()
    :InputObject("file_name.txt", std::ios::in)
{
    if (!InputObject) {
        InputObject.clear();
        InputObject.open("AlternativeFile", std::ios::in)
    }
}
```